# Service bus triggered consumption app not scaling past one instance

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azureservicebus

My function app platform type is Linux with consumption plan and runtime net6.0. I have created Service Bus trigger function and deployed using Visual Studio Publish profile and it is working as expected - *but not scaling*

We have a number of jobs put to queue (around 500k), but it won't go beyond one instance, even while publishing to the bus. The only time we see it go to 2-3 is immediately after a restart or publish.

The trigger uses peek lock and auto complete = false.

With an event hub trigger it scales instances to the number of partitions almost instantly and processes messages at a rate defined by our database throughput.

I have read up on a number of GitHub issues and Stack Overflow questions, which mention among other things; ensuring the scaling controller can access the setting for the queue, using web deploy instead of zip publish, but none have worked.

Comment: Are you using session on the service bus? Do you have Enforced Message Ordering enabled?

Comment: I am not using sessions, and Enforced Message Ordering is not enabled

Comment: It is the same result whether partitioned or not, whether using duplicate detection or not, and with a topic or queue.

Comment: Have you read the "Scale efficiency:" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling ?